# Display only one object at a time from rest API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm training to become better with react and am building a quiz API where I fetch 10 random questions and answers from a JSON list on a rest API.

I was wondering if there is a way to split these 10 questions so they don't all show up at once, but one at a time after having answered the previous one. Which method should I use to achieve this? Is it `split()`? Or any other method? Or can somebody direct me to a tutorial etc. where they actually demonstrate this. I have been googling for the past few days, and I have found absolutely nothing.

EDIT: I am adding my code as this seems to be far more complicated than I thought.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const API =
  "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      score: [],
      question: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      question: this.state.question
    })
    this.populateAppWithData();
  }

  populateAppWithData() {
    const showData = fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results }));
    console.log(showData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz App</h1>
        <TheCounter question={this.state.results}
          Counter={this.state.score}
          right={this.state.correct_answer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class MythologyAnswers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answered: undefined, isRight: undefined
    };
  }
  answerClicked(answer) {
    const { hasAnswered, correct_answer } = this.props;
    return event => {
      if (this.state.answered) return;
      const isRight = correct_answer === answer;
      hasAnswered(isRight);
      this.setState({ answered: answer, isRight });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
    const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="newQuestion">{question}
        {[...incorrect_answers, correct_answer]
          .map(answer => <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer} </div>)} <br />
        {answered && `You answered ${answered}`} <br />
        <div className="correctAnswer"> {answered && isRight && "This is correct!"} </div>
        <div className="incorrectAnswer"> {answered && !isRight && "This is incorrect. please try again"} </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TheCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      right: 0,
      Counter: 0,
    };

  }
  questionAnswered(isRight) {
    this.setState(({ Counter, right }) => ({ Counter: Counter + 1, right: right + isRight }));
  }

  render() {
    const { question } = this.props;
    const { Counter, right } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="newQuestion">
        {question.slice().map(i => <MythologyAnswers key={i.question} {...i}
          hasAnswered={it => this.questionAnswered(it)} />)}
        <div>Counter: {this.state.Counter}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You can get each coming question with `Array.shift` method, it should looks like `let currentQuestion = questions.shift()`. It would be easier to answer if you provide some code.

Comment: I looked for "react quiz tutorial" and found many hits, including [Create a quiz with React](https://mitchgavan.com/react-quiz/)...

Comment: @l-portet that is to shift the questions only as I understand. My main problem right now is to be able to only show one question at a time. right now it's showing all 10 of them. so I would first need to fix that in order to move on to the shifting but I did not know of that method so thanks alot

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did have a look through it and I did find alot of useful information. Unfortunately not what I was looking for though but thanks

Comment: Did you follow through with any other links produced by that search? I got about 1.1 million results when I ran it. That would take me more more than 26 minutes to go through...

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON data you get from the API? Or even the API url.

Comment: @Bman70 this is the api I am fetching the data from https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";


const API =
  "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      score: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateAppWithData();
  }

  populateAppWithData() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results }));
  }

  render() {
    const { results } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz App</h1>
        <TheCounter
          results={results}
          Counter={this.state.score}
          right={this.state.correct_answer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class MythologyAnswers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prevAnswer: "",
      isRight: null
    };
  }
  answerClicked(answer) {
    const { hasAnswered, correct_answer } = this.props;
    return event => {
      const isRight = correct_answer === answer;
      hasAnswered(isRight);
      this.setState({ prevAnswer: answer, isRight });
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
    const { prevAnswer, isRight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="newQuestion">
        {question}
        {incorrect_answers &&
          incorrect_answers
            .concat(correct_answer)
            .map(answer => (
              <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer}</div>
            ))}{" "}
        <br />
        {prevAnswer && `You answered ${prevAnswer}`} <br />
        <div className="correctAnswer">
          {" "}
          {prevAnswer && isRight && "This is correct!"}{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="incorrectAnswer">
          {" "}
          {prevAnswer && !isRight && "This is incorrect. please try again"}{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TheCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      right: 0,
      Counter: 0
    };
  }
  questionAnswered = isRight => {
    this.setState(({ Counter, right }) => ({
      Counter: Counter + 1,
      right: right + isRight // isRight is a boolean. why are we using addition here?
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { results } = this.props;
    const { Counter } = this.state;

    const question = results[Counter];

    return (
      <div className="newQuestion">
        <MythologyAnswers {...question} hasAnswered={this.questionAnswered} />
        <div>Counter: {this.state.Counter}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks. I am not fully aware at the moment of exactly how to use async but I did try your method in my code but it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I am recieving the following error regarding the concat 
TypeError: correct_answer.concat(...).map is not a function

Comment: nevermind it's actually working. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This serves up each quiz with a Javascript `alert`, then  serves up the next one when they click OK. You didn't say if you're taking actual input and comparing it to the right answer, but this way you have all the variables to do that if you want.

**your_json** is what you got from the API:

```
var your_json = {
"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"Mythology","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"This Greek mythological figure is the god\/goddess of battle strategy (among other things).","correct_answer":"Athena","incorrect_answers":["Ares","Artemis","Apollo"]}]
        } //// etc.



var i = 0;

function loopValues(element) {  
  return Object.values([your_json.results[i][element]]);;
}

while (i < 10) {

   var cat = loopValues('category');
   var typ = loopValues('type');
   var dif = loopValues('difficulty');
   var que = loopValues('question');
   var ans = loopValues('correct_answer');
   var not = loopValues(['incorrect_answers'][0]);

    alert("Question " + ([i+1]) + " Category: " + cat);
    alert(que);
    alert("Answer: " + ans);
    
i++;
  
}
```

Comment: Hi

My bad I didn't explain my code well. What I got right now is 10 different questions picked up from the api and they all show up on my screen. In this quiz app I have the correct and incorrect answers below each question and when the user clicks on one of them they get a response that either says that the answer is correct or that it is wrong. The main problem is that I'm getting all the questions and answers up at once but I only what them to show one at a time.

I'm assuming there must be an easier way to do this than to create a while loop with variables for each object in reactjs

Comment: and I don't want to use alerts.. just have one question at a time show up on my screen and when answered move over to the next question

Comment: I see, you already have the JSON parsed and the questions and answers being delivered to the screen. Sample code of course would be the best, showing the code for at least two questions. Without that, I can suggest maybe putting each question in a unique CSS `div`, having only one visible main container `div`, and load each question `div` into the main container as an action is performed.

Comment: I will upload my code where I wrote my first question as I see that I'm not able to write down the full code in the comment section